# Docker connect database from a container (laravel) to other container (wordpress)

Tags: docker

I have two project using docker, in first project is laravel, and second is wordpress. In laravel I want to connect both database (to convert laravel database to wordpress database).

but I don't know how to connect it:
here is two docker-compose.yml file:

in laravel:

```
version: '2'
services:

# The Application
app:
  build:
  context: ./
  dockerfile: app.dockerfile
working_dir: /var/www
volumes:
  - ./:/var/www
environment:
  - "DB_PORT=3306"
  - "DB_HOST=database"

# The Web Server
web:
  build:
    context: ./
    dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes_from:
       - app
    ports:
      - 8081:80

 # The Database
  database:
    image: mysql:5.6
    volumes:
     - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=homestead"
      - "MYSQL_USER=homestead"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret"
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
    ports:
       - "33061:3306"
 volumes:
   dbdata:
```

and my docker-compose.yml file in wordpress:

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
   environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wpshop
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123456

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
       - ./:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: 123456
   volumes:
      db_data:
```

I cd to each project and run docker-compose up -d

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Create an external network and use that network as default network for all your containers. This way you'll be able to reach all container by its name.

Take a look to Docker container networking: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/